# Error using Lodash in Postman

Tags: postman

i have the following code inside a Test script in Postman

```
var _ = require('lodash');

tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

tests["Data is present"] = !!data;
var newData=environment["results"];

var diff=_.xorWith(data, newData, _.isEqual);
```

but when run in test gives me

> Cannot find module 'lodash'
>   Error

how can i use it ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution; it was 2 things togheter:

1. there was a bug on Postman which didn't load properly some functions
2. Postman support only version 3.x not the last 4.x so many useful functions (like XorWith) are simply not available

thanks all for the time

Answer (score 1):

Though postman support only Lodash version 3.10.2
still you can use lodash latest version by declaring new variable.

```
console.log(_.VERSION);
    // 3.10.2

dash = require('lodash');
console.log(dash.VERSION);
    //4.17.15
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit silly, but have you considered removing

> var _ = require('lodash');

I've never required to mention it in any of my tests. Simply use the method you require, which is clearly:

> _.xorWith

See what error, if any, springs forth thereafter.

Comment: Yes i did, that was my first try but it gives me "'There was an error in evaluating the test script:  _.xorWith is not a function" in tests window

Comment: I've just tried using some lodash methods, Sugar methods, and Sugar methods which call lodash methods within them, and the only issue I had was when trying to use specific Sugar methods, and I got the same error message ("...is not a method")
I suspect Postman is either using a dumbed-down library of both, or an outdated library. I realise this doesn't help you, though.