# Extract nested JSON array response object using JS Lodash in Postman

Tags: json, postman, lodash

I want to learn how to use Lodash to extract variables from a JSON response because the traditional methods explained on other Postman questions do not explain an easy way to do this as I used to do it with json path in Jmeter.

I need to translate the following json paths to a Lodash expression that returns the same values as this JSON paths

```
1. FlightSegmentsItinerary[*].Flights[*].Key 
2. $..Flights[*].Key
3. Travelers[*].[?(@.TypeCode == "INF")].FirstName (returns the name of the passangers whose type code are == "INF")
```

JSON Response:

```
 {
"Travelers": [
    {
        "TypeCode": "ADT",
        "FirstName": "FULANO",
        "Surname": "LAZARO",
        "Key": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "TypeCode": "INF",
        "FirstName": "MENGANO",
        "Surname": "XULO",
        "Key": "2.2"
    }
],
"FlightSegmentsItinerary": [
    {
        "Flights": [
            {
                "Key": "1"
            },
            {
                "Key": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

So far I was able to extract the travelers Keys (Travelers[*].Key) using this:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();    
var travelerKeys = _.map(jsonData.Travelers, 'Key');
console.log("travelerKeys: " + travelerKeys);
Output: travelerKeys: 1.1,2.2
```

As you can see, the JSON path:

> Travelers[*].Key

Looks like this in Lodash:

> var travelerKeys = _.map(jsonData.Travelers, 'Key');

for this case.

Comment: is there any difference in the result of the first 2 JSON paths, and do all 3 JSON paths result in array/multiple items ?

Comment: no xD, those 2 return the same, I was just wondering the different ways to get the same result. and yes, all of them should return an array with multiple items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var jsonData = {
  "Travelers": [{
      "TypeCode": "ADT",
      "FirstName": "FULANO",
      "Surname": "LAZARO",
      "Key": "1.1"
    },
    {
      "TypeCode": "INF",
      "FirstName": "MENGANO",
      "Surname": "XULO",
      "Key": "2.2"
    }
  ],
  "FlightSegmentsItinerary": [{
    "Flights": [{
        "Key": "1"
      },
      {
        "Key": "2"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

// 1. FlightSegmentsItinerary[*].Flights[*].Key 
console.log( _(jsonData.FlightSegmentsItinerary).flatMap('Flights').map('Key') ) 

//2. $..Flights[*].Key
console.log( _.chain(jsonData).values().flatten().find('Flights').values().flatten().map('Key') )

//3. Travelers[*].[?(@.TypeCode == "INF")].FirstName (returns the name of the passangers whose type code are == "INF")
console.log( _(jsonData.Travelers).filter(['TypeCode', 'INF']).map('FirstName') )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

Another option might be to try JavaScript libraries such as https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath

```js
var jsonData = {
  "Travelers": [{
      "TypeCode": "ADT",
      "FirstName": "FULANO",
      "Surname": "LAZARO",
      "Key": "1.1"
    },
    {
      "TypeCode": "INF",
      "FirstName": "MENGANO",
      "Surname": "XULO",
      "Key": "2.2"
    }
  ],
  "FlightSegmentsItinerary": [{
    "Flights": [{
        "Key": "1"
      },
      {
        "Key": "2"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

console.log(jsonpath.query(jsonData, '$.FlightSegmentsItinerary[*].Flights[*].Key'))

console.log(jsonpath.query(jsonData, '$..Flights[*].Key'))

console.log(jsonpath.query(jsonData, '$.Travelers..[?(@.TypeCode == "INF")].FirstName'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonpath@1.0.2/jsonpath.min.js"></script>
```

Because Postman doesn't support `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`, the jsonpath.min.js file contents can be saved in environment variable, and then `eval(pm.environment.get('jsonpath'));` before use as described in
https://community.getpostman.com/t/adding-external-libraries-to-postman/1971/4

Comment: I'm trying with Lodash since it comes with Postman. As you say, I am having troubles with Postman, I get the error: "TypeError | Cannot read property 'flatMap' of undefined". I'm going to try a workaround for this.

Comment: @Victor the issue is not with `flatMap` but with what is before it not being found. If `jsonData.Travelers` works, then I don't see a reason why `jsonData.FlightSegmentsItinerary` would not work .. maybe spelling or case mistake?

Comment: I tried with these: `console.log( obj.FlightSegmentsItinerary.flatten(o => o.Flights).map(o => o.Key) );` -> **returns empty array**. then I did `console.log( obj.FlightSegmentsItinerary_.flatMap(o => o.Flights).map(o => o.Key) );` and it returns "TypeError | Cannot read property 'flatMap' of undefined".

Comment: then I did obj.FlightSegmentsItinerary.flatMap(o => o.Flights).map(o => o.Key) -> returns TypeError | obj.FlightSegmentsItinerary.flatMap is not a function and lastly obj.FlightSegmentsItinerary.flat(o => o.Flights).map(o => o.Key) - > TypeError | obj.FlightSegmentsItinerary.flat is not a function". I also added the var obj to test, but yea, I could use the var jsonData I already have.

Comment: Thanks for the update! the second line of code worked for the nested array! `console.log( _.chain(jsonData).values().flatten().find('Flights').values().flatten().map('Key') );` I'm going to study this so I keep working on the different jsonpaths I already had on jmeter.

Comment: @Victor I added a jsonpath example that might be a bit easier than learning Lodash

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Postman which Sandbox module you going to use using `require` function(refer below code). The error you get has some issue with Postman few of them works few of them not [Here they are talking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38871506/5400362)
and [Here is the postman issue tracker](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues)

the code I tried and worked for me as

```
const moment = require('lodash');
var keys = _.chain(obj.Travelers)
        .map("Key")
        .flatten()
        .unique()
        .value();
console.log(keys);
```

**output**

```
Array:[]
0 : "1.1"
1 : "2.2"
```

form more details you can look at
[Postman Sandbox API reference](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference)
[postman-and-lodash-the-perfect-partnership](https://dannydainton.com/2018/09/01/postman-and-lodash-the-perfect-partnership/)

Comment: I already got that from using only this: var travelerKeys = _.map(jsonData.Travelers, 'Key');.Hence this actually does not answers the real question which are the keys inside the FlightSegmentsItinerary that are actually deeper than the Travelers keys. Also, I had this: var _ = require('lodash'); and your code did not work at first. Then I change it to const moment = require('lodash'); and it did work. Still, I like the answer, I need to study its properties to see how I can get the nested array of Key inside FlightSegmentsItinerary.